# Primitive element theorem for finite fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> Primitive element theorem for finite fields

Can you explain $2$ points in the proof of the proposition below

$\bullet$ First $\alpha$ is the root of the polynomial $T^{p^s}-T$, because $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ is an extension field and in particular it is a group, so $\alpha^{p^s-1}=1$, for any nonzero $\alpha$, am I correct

$\bullet$ Second, Why do we sum up the number of roots, are they all distinct, I don't get the conclusion

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first point is correct. Expressing it as $T^{p^s}-T$ ensures that $0$ is also a root.

For the second part, the idea is as follows: if $\alpha\in K$ in not a primitive element, then $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ will be a proper subfield of $K$ - i.e. a finite field of order $p^s$ for some $s<r$ - and $\alpha$ will satisfy the polynomial $T^{p^s}-T$.

The proof then proceeds by a counting argument. Each $\alpha\in K$ that isn't a primitive element is the root of a polynomial $T^{p^s}-T$. And each such polynomial has at most $p^s$ roots. So the total number of elements of $K$ which are *not* primitive elements will be at most the total number of roots of polynomials of the form $T^{p^s}-T$, i.e.
$$\#\{\alpha\in K:\alpha \text{ is not a primitive element}\} \le \sum_{s=1}^{r-1}p^s<p^r$$
So the number of *non*-primitive elements is less than $|K| = p^r$. Hence, there must be a primitive element.